# WordPress Custom Rewrite Rules: Query String

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this url

```
mydomain.com/blog.html?comments=%number%
```

to a WordPress post of the id `%number%` like so:

```
mywordpressdomain.com/?p=%number%
```

I am fighting with this for quite some time now and can not figure it out. Question mark should divide the url into querystring and the rest, right? Thanks.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I added `add_rewrite_rule( '^blog.html?comments=([0-9]{4})$', 'index.php?&p=$matches[2]', 'top');`, I understand it doesn't work, because "?" is a part of regex, of course.